# Halal or Haram income sources

Tags: halal-haram, money

Assalamu Alaikum!
  I am working in a company other than Purchasing Dept. In short if instead of giving my due increment, my immediate management gives me chance to deal with the suppliers to buy material used in my department, is it halal for me to get some benefit in terms of money from the suppliers by giving them the business or not.
And is it Halal to get any goods or services from someone and give to other and make some money in between?

Thanks and waiting for the reply.

Comment: Trading itself is ok (buying + selling goods)... if the supplier gives you personally money to make you give him the business then that is haram!

Comment: It's fine as long as it's honestly done. The line for corruption can be very blurry. As long as you are getting paid for what you've agreed to do and aren't using your position to coerce/trick someone into paying you, it should be fine. If he's paying you in valuable things instead of money, that's fine as long as he's not using it as a tax loophole or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is trading all about. You take goods from one and give to another. It's permissible as in http://quran.com/2/275